# File upload and read from database

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am using file upload mechanism to upload file for an employee and converting it into byte[] and passing it to varBinary(Max) to store into database.

Now I what I have to do is, if any file is already uploaded for employee, simply read it from table and show file name. I have only one column to store a file and which is of type VarBinary.

Is it possible to get all file information from VarBinary field?

Any other way around, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not storing the filename, you can't retrieve it.

(Unless the file itself contains its filename in which case you'd need to parse the blob's contents.)

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the file (and any other data about the file that's not part of the file's byte data) needs to be used later, then you need to save that data as well.  I'd recommend adding a column for the file name, perhaps one for its type (mime type or something like that for properly sending it back to the client's browser, etc.) and maybe even one for size so you don't have to calculate that on the fly for each file (useful when displaying a grid of files and not wanting to touch the large blob field in the query that populates the grid).

Try to stay away from using the file name for system-internal identity purposes.  It's fine for allowing the users to search for a file by name, select it, etc.  But when actually making the request to the server to display the file it's better to use a simple integer primary key from the table to actually identify it.  (On a side note, it's probably a good idea to put a unique constraint on the file name column.)

If you also need help displaying the file to the user, you'll probably want to take the approach that's tried and true for displaying images from a database.  Basically it involves having a resource (generally an .aspx page, but could just as well be an `HttpHandler` instead) which accepts the file ID as a query string parameter and outputs the file.

This resource would have no UI (remove everything from the .aspx except the Page directive) and would manually manipulate the response headers (this is where you'd set the content type from the file's type), write the byte stream to the client, and end the response.  From the client's perspective, something like `~/MyContent/MyFile.aspx?fileID=123` would *be* the file.  (You can suggest a file name to the browser for saving purposes in the response headers, which you'd probably want to do with the file's stored name.)

There's no shortage of [quick tutorials](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx) (some several years old, it's been around for a while) on how to do this with images.  Just remember that there's essentially no difference from the server's perspective if it's an image or any other kind of file.  All the server needs to do is send the type in the response headers and write the file's bytes to the client.  How the client handles the file is up to the browser.  In the vast majority of cases, the browser will know what to do (display an image, display via a plugin a PDF, save a .doc, etc.).